# Stange query peformance: fast from SSMS, slow from app (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, ado.net

Well, I know. **'fast from SSMS, slow from app'** - that sounds very familiar for someone.
One can start thinking about parameter sniffing or connection settings. But I guess that's not the case for me.

So that's the query:

```
SELECT [ST].*, [STL].*
FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction] AS [ST] 
    LEFT JOIN [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] AS [STL] ON ([STL] [StockTransaction_id] = [ST].[id]) 
WHERE 
([ST].[Type] IN (0, 1, 10, 9)
AND ([STL].[Direction] IN (0, 1) OR [STL].[id] IS NULL) 
AND [ST].[Status] IN (0,1)
AND ( ([STL].[StockContainer_id] = 300000742600 OR [STL].[id] IS NULL) AND [ST].[StockContainerID] = 300000742600))
```

I'll post links to images of execution plans, if you don't mind (pls tell in comments), cause there's gonna be many of them.

Execution plan that I get from SSMS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7sBR.png (runs fraction of a sec)

Execution plan, that's used for query when it's executed from app:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqBq.png (runs ~3sec)

So, for some reason, sql-server makes wrong estimations and prefers a table scan in second case.

The query is built dynamically and new plan is generated for each new value of StockContainerID (no parameters).

Well, okay, so gave up trying to figure out the problem and just used **FORCESEEK** hint:

```
SELECT [ST].*, [STL].*
FROM [WP_CashCenter_StockTransaction] AS [ST] WITH(FORCESEEK)
    LEFT JOIN [WP_CashCenter_StockTransactionLine] AS [STL] WITH(FORCESEEK) ON ([STL].[StockTransaction_id] = [ST].[id])
```

Now, the execution plans seem to be identical:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnf19.png (executed from app). But it still takes ~3secs.

Take a look at this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSxXE.png (SSMS, 1 number of executions, 1 estimated rows)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKNKe.png (app, 1 numer of executions, 655k estimated rows)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RoQl.png (SSMS, 1 numebr of executions, 1 estimated rows)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgi23.png (app, 655k number of executions, 1 estimated rows)

You should have noticed that the second plan uses parallelism. I don't know if that can be a reason for the problem (I think no).

Comment: What's the query that gets executed from app? In the first query, you have a where clause that reduces the columns returned from each table before join. If you add that same clause to the second query, the one with forceseek, does it still take 3 seconds?

Comment: Before doing any query speed test, consider executing `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. Unless it's a production server.

Comment: I have `where` condition in both queries (there's actually a single query, I just run it from SSMS). yes, I've executed `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`